# c# cannot connect to sql localdb when moved to another computer

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am writing a program for my engineering teacher, which is connected to a MS SQL localDB. My problem is that the program works flawlessly on my computer, but when I move it to the computer that it is going to be used on, the program cannot connect to the database (I will update the post this afternoon when I get a chance to copy the exception). I have SQL Server 2008 and 2014 installed on my computer. The localDB was created on the 2008 engine. The computer that I am trying to run it on is Windows XP with SQL Server 2008 Express, and with .NET 4.0 (the .NET program itself starts up, but only crashes when I do anything related to the LocalDB).

My connection string is as follows:

```
public const string conString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Parts.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

And I also tried:

```
public const string conString = @"Data Source=DAVIDS_LAPTOP;Initial Catalog=X:\PARTS.MDF;Integrated Security=True";
```

If the solution would work on Windows XP with SQL Server 2008 Express, it would be highly appreciated,though not absolutely necessary.

I've tried everything I could think of (albeit, I'm new to SQL). I've also tried to Google it, but to no avail

Edit:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/v6k76jrchxf7agr/AAA1H66di5dndo19WSm-p0XZa?dl=0

Comment: I will @JNYRanger in a little bit, as it works on my computer without throwing any error messages and I do not have access to another computer at this moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is twofold:  One is that you're using SQL Server 2008 and the other is that you're using Windows XP.  LocalDB was introduced as part of SQL Server 2012 and is only supported in Windows Vista SP2 / Server 2008 R2 and later.

The LocalDB could not have been created with the 2008 engine as it was not supported in that version, however you may have set compatibility mode within SSMS.  This however will still not allow a LocalDB to work with a SQL Server 2008 driver.

The reason why it works locally is because you have SQL Server 2014 installed.  This has the drivers to allow for communication to the LocalDB instance.

If you want to use the SQL Server 2008 R2 instance, then you won't be able to use LocalDB / embedding and you'll need to connect to the actual SQL Server [Express] instance that the database resides.  If you want to embed a database and you're using Windows XP (and your dataset / needs aren't large) you should use [SQL Server Compact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142).

Here's an article about the requirements of SQL Server LocalDB (this pertains to 2012, but it's pretty much the same as 2014): [What is LocalDB?](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/sqlserver2012_0004.htm)

Main Source:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx

Comment: Thank JNYRanger! Although it is a depressing fact, it ultimately solves my issue, and I appreciate the advice about the SQL Server Compact. I'll ask my teacher if he could get a new computer (highly likely, but if it is not going to happen soon, then I will definitely transfer to SQL Server Compact

Comment: @DavidKluszczynski No problem.  SQL Server Compact may be exactly what you're looking for especially if you're only storing limited data sets (smaller than 4GB) and you don't need the power of a full database server.